# Decomposition of a fraction by a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fractions

Let be two sequences of real numbers $a = [a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ and $b = [b_1,\ldots , b_n]$. Is it possible to represent the fraction:

$$
F(a,b) = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i }{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j }
$$

As a sum of terms such as each one is defined only by the previous numbers in the sequences?

$$
F(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(i)
$$

with:

$$
f(i) = f( a_1, ..., a_i, b_1, ..., b_i )
$$

while avoiding trivial cases ($f(n)=F(a,b)$, $f(i) = 0 \forall i \in [1,n[$, $f(i) = \text{constant}$, etc.).

Comment: Every sequence can be written as a series; the summands of the series are the differences between between successive terms of the sequence.

Comment: Requesting clarification, may I confirm that the question means $$f(i) = f(a_1,\ldots, a_i; b_1, \ldots b_i) = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^i a_j}{\sum_{j=1}^i b_j}-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_j}{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} b_j};\\f(1) = f(a_1; b_1) = \frac{a_1}{b_1}$$? (And if no partial sum of sequence $b$ is zero)

Comment: @peterwhy: yes, this would work indeed